# Add to Array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to initliaize one but how do add I items to an Array? I heard it was `push()` maybe? I can't find it...

Comment: What do you want to add to what array?

Comment: Are you asking how to add elements to an Array, or how to add elements to a jQuery object?

Comment: @Jahkr: Then what does jQuery have to do with it?

Comment: I'm doing the arrays in jQuery...

Comment: @Jahkr: You're also probably sitting on a chair whilst doing it, but that doesn't mean that the question is relevant to Ikea. Don't be misled thinking that jQuery is a separate language; it is not. You're still writing Javascript. You just happen to be using things from the jQuery library (in _other parts_ of your code).

Answer (score 323, accepted):

For JavaScript arrays, you use `push()`.

```
var a = [];
a.push(12);
a.push(32);
```

For jQuery objects, there's `add()`.

```
$('div.test').add('p.blue');
```

Note that while `push()` modifies the original array in-place, `add()` returns a new jQuery object, it does not modify the original one.

Comment: +1 for explaining both JavaScript and jQuery's method and their fundamental difference.  I came here for `$.add()` and got just a little bit more.

Answer (score 30):

[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a native javascript method. You could use it like this:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.push(4); // array now is [1, 2, 3, 4]
array.push(5, 6, 7); // array now is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 14):

You are right. This has nothing to do with jQuery though.

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push("foo");
// myArray now contains "foo" at index 0.
```

Comment: nice, but how do I add foo at index 'customString' ?

Comment: ha! I found it myArray.push( {'index':'value'} );

Comment: But that is no longer array then, myArray turns into object?

Answer (score 4):

For JavaScript arrays, you use Both push() and concat() function.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.push(4, 5);         //use push for appending a single array.




var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [4, 5, 6];

var array3 = array1.concat(array2);   //It is better use concat for appending more then one array.
```

Answer (score 2):

just it jquery

```
var linkModel = {
            Link: "",
            Url: "",
            Summary: "",
        };

var model = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
    linkModel.Link = "Test.com" + i;
    linkModel.Url= "www.Test.com" + i;
    linkModel.Summary= "Test is add" + i;
    model.Links.push(linkModel);
}
```